# Have 2 unknown smb network shares on my ubuntu machine

Tags: networking, samba, security, smb

today I noticed something strange about my machine, it has the following two smb shares that I have never seen before, is this a normal behavior? I been trying to get rid of them but no luck. PLEASE HELP[image: What I see]

Comment: This could happen if you have connected to a network where someone else offers an open share called Konichiwa. It is their security problem, not yours. The Konichiwa share will be gone once you reboot, and then so will the Windows Network icon.

Comment: @Jos thank you so much! This makes sense now!

Comment: Allow me to post my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This could happen if you have connected to a network where someone else offers an open share called `konichiwa`. Your system runs an SMB client that sends out broadcast packets, basically asking around for SAMBA shares, much like your network card finds Wi-Fi networks to connect to. If a share is found, and if it allows guest access with no password, it will be mounted, and be accessible to you.

Keep in mind that this is their security problem, not yours. Whereas you can access their share, they will not be able to access your system.

The `konichiwa` share will be gone once you reboot, and then so will the Windows Network icon (which is a pool of all SAMBA shares that are currently available to you).